# Bridged network VirtualBox to VMware on the same host can't ping each other

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have several VMs on a single host running in both VMware and VirtualBox. All of the VMs are using a bridged interface(all on the same NIC) to access the network the host is connected to. Host OS is Windows.

The issue I am having is that when I initially set this up I was able to ping VMs in VMware from VMs in VirtualBox over this shared bridged connection, but occasionally I find the VMs are unable to ping each other. I haven't made any changes to the configuration of the VMs or the host, and all of the VMs are able to reach other systems on the network.

Example:

- VMware VM IP 192.168.0.105
- VirtualBox VM IP 192.168.0.104
- host IP 192.168.0.106
- second PC IP 192.168.0.110

Both VMs live on the host.
The VMware VM can ping the host and second PC.
VirtualBox can ping the host and second PC.
But VMware and VirtualBox cannot ping each other.

Comment: You don't mention the host OS, but do you have any Firewall software (either native or third party) and have you checked its logs?

Comment: all using the same NIC?  you could be seeing conflicts between the networking layers added by VMware and Vbox.  Why use two different hypervisors?

Comment: @DaveWhite this is running on windows for the host, the only firewall I have would be the default one. Do you know where I would be able to find any logs for it?

Comment: @essjae Yes they are using the same NIC. I started off using virtualbox and prefer the interface, but vmware has better support for nested VMs. So I run most things on virtualbox and the ones that need the nested VMs on vmware.

Comment: @ColinZ for Windows Defender firewall settings and log check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028544/windows-10-turn-microsoft-defender-firewall-on-or-off), [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/all/windows-defender-security-where-are-av-and/d76933e0-6e1a-49b6-9385-d4d39e33e9a2) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/configure-the-windows-firewall-log)

Comment: Did it resolve through a Windows Defender configuration change in your case? How did you bridge them to the same physical network in the first place?

Comment: @matt I still haven't been able to resolve the issue. I did the bridges by just telling each vm to bridge on the one ethernet adapter on my PC.